# Gnome shortcut to focus a particular screen

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, arch-linux, gnome

I am coming from i3 background, so I like to use my keyboard a lot. I recently switched to gnome and I miss one functionality.

For now I place my windows on separate workspaces and displays (got 3 of them). Now let's say I editing a file on a workspace 1 and monitor 1 (lets say monitors are 1->2->3 from the left). Now I save the file and I want to run the tests from a terminal which is on a workspace 1, but on monitor 3. Normally, on i3, the terminal would be just on a workspace 3 (so I could Super+3 to it). Now I can switch a workspace, but I cannot switch a monitor.

Is there a way to do this in gnome 3?

Answer (score 1):

As an old i3 user I have been missing this movements as well. I wrote a Gnome extension to be able to change focus in different direction. It works in multi monitor setups as well.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4627/focus-changer/

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but it might cover your use case :

https://hyperkeys.xureilab.com

You can pin a window with a shortcut (Say ALT+SHIFT+A) and bring it to focus with another (Say ALT+A).

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you may try is [Pop OS Shell](https://support.system76.com/articles/pop-keyboard-shortcuts/). This brings a similar experience of i3 (although not as powerful as i3). You can hit `Super-H` twice to move to the right from monitor 1 to monitor 3.

There is also [material shell](https://material-shell.com/), which is even closer to i3 experience.